# sql update next day no row effect

Tags: sql, sql-update, dateadd

I want update tomorrow if today overtime work. But I have some problem no row effect.
lembur_time = overtime work type data int

```
update kkpsurabaya 
set clock_in='' 
where lembur_time >=240 
    and name='yuyun dwi astutik' 
    and date = DATEADD(day, 1, '2016-05-26')
```

(0 row(s) affected) if use syntax like that but if

```
update kkpsurabaya 
set clock_in='' 
where name = 'yuyun dwi astutik' 
    and date = DATEADD(day, 1, '2016-05-26')
```

without lembur_time >= 240 this work

I tried

```
select Name, lembur_time 
from kkpsurabaya 
WHERE lembur_time >=240
```

and I have data with name yuyun dwi astutik lembur_time = 245

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlrY2.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW1Ka.png)

Comment: What's the datatype of clock_in and  lembur_time?

Comment: clock_in type data time lembur_tme

Comment: I don't get it? Is it datetime both?

Comment: clock in is time and lembur_time is int

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM kkpsurabaya  where lembur_time >=240 and name='yuyun dwi astutik' and date = DATEADD(day, 1, '2016-05-26')' run this query and check the result.

Comment: that no result man becaus no lembur time in 2016-05-27, i want update tomorow  if today overtimework

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (DATEADD is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set empty string to `time` data type column, set it to null

```
Update kkpsurabaya 
Set 
   clock_in=null 
Where
      lembur_time >=240 
And name='yuyun dwi astutik' 
And date = DATEADD(day, 1, Convert(date, getdate())) //
```

Comment: still 
(0 row(s) affected)

Comment: Check the database..sometimes it gives false report

Comment: how i can check that?

Comment: I mean to check whether the row is updated or not in the database directly

Comment: that realy no change in 2016-05-27 clock_in = 07:30, this problem is only in lembur_time >= 240  other where is work if i add lembur_time >= 240 that no row affect

Answer (score 0):

maybe i miss something or wrong query , in my brain i want:
update clock_in = null in date 2016-05-27
where date now is = 2016-05-26 and lembur_time >=240

Comment: Can you add some sample from your table and I'm sure the problem will be solve. It's really easy task

Comment: i add image in my post

Comment: You did not included column name(header)

Comment: The query is working as it is suppose to? Tell me what exactly is it that you want to achieve

Comment: i want update clock_in tomorrow where lembur_time >= 240

Comment: tommorrow is , today date 08/08/2016 tomorrow = 09/08/2016

Comment: But Clock_in is time, you cannot set date to time

Comment: that null becaus i use query "update kkpsurabaya 
set clock_in='' 
where name = 'yuyun dwi astutik' 
    and date = DATEADD(day, 1, '2016-05-26')"

Comment: i just want make that null if lembur_time >= 240 if no higher that 240 that no null